# How/when to release memory in wait-free algorithms

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, asynchronous, data-structures

I'm having trouble figuring out a key point in wait-free algorithm design. Suppose a data structure has a pointer to another data structure (e.g. linked list, tree, etc), how can the right time for releasing a data structure?

The problem is this, there are separate operations that can't be executed atomically without a lock. For example one thread reads the pointer to some memory, and increments the use count for that memory to prevent free while this thread is using the data, which might take long, and even if it doesn't, it's a race condition. What prevents another thread from reading the pointer, decrementing the use count and determining that it's no longer used and freeing it before the first thread incremented the use count?

The main issue is that current CPUs only have a single word CAS (compare & swap). Alternatively the problem is that I'm clueless about waitfree algorithms and data structures and after reading some papers I'm still not seeing the light.

IMHO Garbage collection can't be the answer, because it would either GC would have to be prevented from running if any single thread is inside an atomic block (which would mean it can't be guaranteed that the GC will ever run again) or the problem is simply pushed to the GC, in which case, please explain how the GC would figure out if the data is in the silly state (a pointer is read [e.g. stored in a local variable] but the the use count didn't increment yet).

PS, references to advanced tutorials on wait-free algorithms for morons are welcome.

Edit: You should assume that the problem is being solved in a non-managed language, like C or C++. After all if it were Java, we'd have no need to worry about releasing memory. Further assume that the compiler may generate code that will store temporary references to objects in registers (invisible to other threads) right before the usage counter increment, and that a thread can be interrupted between loading the object address and incrementing the counter. This of course doesn't mean that the solution must be limited to C or C++, rather that the solution should give a set of primitives that allowing the implementation of wait-free algorithms on linked data structures. I'm interested in the primitives and how they solve the problem of designing wait-free algorithms. With such primitives a wait-free algorithm can be implemented equally well in C++ and Java.

Comment: The folks around the Linux kernel are keenly interested in lockless algorithms, particularly RCU. See [Documentation/RCU/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/RCU) in your kernel sources.

Comment: @vonbrand thanks, I totally forgot that, it was a LONG time since I had a look at RCU, I'll have to re-read the docs again to see how it factors into this.

Comment: You asked, *What prevents another thread from reading the pointer, decrementing the use count and determining that it's no longer used and freeing it before the first thread incremented the use count?* The answer is nothing at all. If threads break the rules, then all bets are off. After all, a lock or mutex is a *cooperative* mutual exclusion device. Lock free algorithms also depend on cooperation.

Comment: @JimMischel My question is more along the lines of "how do wait-free algorithms ensure this doesn't happen", i.e. what method is used to induce cooperation. Specifically, if you have a pointer, how do you ensure the data isn't freed after the value is copied in a different thread without a lock. With a mutex it's easy, but how do you do it without one.

Comment: You could use [tombstones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(programming)) to reduce the size of the memory leak, but I believe that the state of the art is concurrent GC. I have no idea how it works.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat no good, as I said in the question, GC isn't an answer without explaining how the GC knows when it's safe to free something. And would tombstones prevent memory leaks? Merely reducing leaks is insufficient. If so, how can this be done concurrently and safely? Is this how wait-free algorithms work?

Comment: Yes, it's not an answer. How concurrent GC works is too broad of a question.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'm only interested in knowing how the GC knows the memory is safe to free (i.e. no unaccounted for pointer, see the question for the specific case I'm worried about and puzzled by). The rest of the GC problem is not related to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understood your question. But here is my 2cents based on my experience with wait free algorithms. You write them in Java and rely on its GC. Most of the recent (2010 onwards) concurrent algorithms for tree based data structures are written in Java. Or if you use C/C++ then GC has to be part of your algorithm

Comment: @arunmoezhi How does the GC know if (in C/C++) that a memory is or isn't pointed to from a local variable? See the question, I'm expanding on this problem. Do you know how this edge case is prevented?

Comment: GC will not know. But your algorithm can be designed to know. For example you can mark a node saying that it is deleted and maintain an invariant that once a node is marked, it is no longer part of the data structure and the memory location can be released by any thread.

Comment: @arunmoezhi In that case you're essentially saying I have to disable GC (by preventing it from reaping the objects) and implement "some logic" ... I still need to release the memory at some point, the tricky question is "how do I figure out when I can release the 'deleted' node?", or in other words "how do I figure out when a deleted object is no longer referenced from anywhere at all?" ... so, what is the secret sauce, the "some logic"?

Comment: yes you can disable GC. You don't have to delete an object only when it is no longer referenced by any thread. Once the invariant that a node will no longer be part of the data structure is satisfied, it can be released. Now some threads will be holding a reference to a location which is invalid. But that's ok. They will not affect the correctness of the algorithm (You have to ensure this as well :) )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49334/discussion-between-martin-and-arunmoezhi)

Comment: I'm not wait-free expert, but the discussion thus far about pointers being shared resources is exactly correct. I think an approach that would work is to maintain a table of pointers to currently allocated objects. The pointers in this table are 1-off references. Manage access to the object by compare with and swap NULL on these table elements. A `free` op that owns the pointer after such a swap can be sure no other thread was in the process of updating the refcount of the object it points to.

Comment: But isn't that a complicated and inefficient mutex on the pointer? If it is the algorithm is no longer wait-free. If a pointer is swapped to null, then the thread is interrupted no other thread can follow the reference, must wait for the previous thread to complete updating the pointer. It would work, but not be wait-free. That's the tricky bit, making this safe (no bad reference ever followed), reliable (all objects freed), efficient (objects freed as soon as possible [otherwise there's no upper bound on memory usage]) and wait-free (ALL threads ALWAYS progress in BOUNDED time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I learned this.

The problem is not trivial to solve and there are several solutions each with advantages and disadvantages. The reason for the complexity comes from inter CPU synchronization issues. If not done right it might appear to work correctly 99.9% of the time, which isn't enough, or it might fail under load.

Three solutions that I found are 1) hazard pointers, 2) quiescence period based reclamation (used by the Linux kernel in the RCU implementation) 3) reference counting techniques. 4) Other 5) Combinations

Hazard pointers work by saving the currently active references in a well-known per thread location, so any thread deciding to free memory (when the counter appears to be zero) can check if the memory is still in use by anyone. An interesting improvement is to buffer request to release memory in a small array and free them up in a batch when the array is full. The advantage of using hazard pointers is that it can actually guarantee an upper bound on unreclaimed memory. The disadvantage is that it places extra burden on the reader.

Quiescence period based reclamation works by delaying the actual release of the memory until it's known that each thread has had a chance to finish working on any data that may need to be released. The way to know that this condition is satisfied is to check if each thread passed through a quiescent period (not in a critical section) after the object was removed. In the Linux kernel this means something like each task making a voluntary task switch. In a user space application it would be the end of a critical section. This can be achieved by a simple counter, each time the counter is even the thread is not in a critical section (reading shared data), each time the counter is odd the thread is inside a critical section, to move from a critical section or back all the thread needs to do is to atomically increment the number. Based on this the "garbage collector" can determine if each thread has had a chance to finish. There are several approaches, one simple one would be to queue up the requests to free memory (e.g. in a linked list or an array), each with the current generation (managed by the GC), when the GC runs it checks the state of the threads (their state counters) to see if each passed to the next generation (their counter is higher than the last time or is the same and even), any memory can be reclaimed one generation after it was freed. The advantage of this approach is that is places the least burden on the reading threads. The disadvantage is that it can't guarantee an upper bound for the memory waiting to be released (e.g. one thread spending 5 minutes in a critical section, while the data keeps changing and memory isn't released), but in practice it works out all right.

There is a number of reference counting solutions, many of them require double compare and swap, which some CPUs don't support, so can't be relied upon. The key problem remains though, taking a reference before updating the counter. I didn't find enough information to explain how this can be done simply and reliably though. So .....

There are of course a number of "Other" solutions, it's a very important topic of research with tons of papers out there. I didn't examine all of them. I only need one.

And of course the various approaches can be combined, for example hazard pointers can solve the problems of reference counting. But there's a nearly infinite number of combinations, and in some cases a spin lock might theoretically break wait-freedom, but doesn't hurt performance in practice. Somewhat like another tidbit I found in my research, it's theoretically not possible to implement wait-free algorithms using compare-and-swap, that's because in theory (purely in theory) a CAS based update might keep failing for non-deterministic excessive times (imagine a million threads on a million cores each trying to increment and decrement the same counter using CAS). In reality however it rarely fails more than a few times (I suspect it's because the CPUs spend more clocks away from CAS than there are CPUs, but I think if the algorithm returned to the same CAS on the same location every 50 clocks and there were 64 cores there could be a chance of a major problem, then again, who knows, I don't have a hundred core machine to try this). Another results of my research is that designing and implementing wait-free algorithms and data-structures is VERY challenging (even if some of the heavy lifting is outsourced, e.g. to a garbage collector [e.g. Java]), and might perform less well than a similar algorithm with carefully placed locks.

So, yeah, it's possible to free memory even without delays. It's just tricky. And if you forget to make the right operations atomic, or to place the right memory barrier, oh, well, you're toast. :-) Thanks everyone for participating.

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Maybe, but nobody gave me a real answer so I summarized my findings so far so anyone interested might get a head start. Then again, IMHO it does explain how it can be done. If you care to give me a proper answer, I'd love to see your input. :-)

Comment: CAS is not wait-free because at most one thread makes progress at a time  and succeeds with the CAS while the others fail and must retry. Wait-free means all threads make progress. Lock xadd is a simple example of wait-free, as all threads executing it succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best way but it works for me:

for shared dynamic data-structure lists I use usage counter per item

- for example:

  ```
  struct _data
   {
   DWORD usage;
   bool  delete;
   // here add your data
   _data() { usage=0; deleted=true; }
   };
  const int MAX = 1024; 
  _data data[MAX];
  ```
- now when item is started to be used somwhere then

  ```
  // start use of data[i]
  data[i].cnt++;
  ```
- after is no longer used then

  ```
  // stop use of data[i]
  data[i].cnt--;
  ```
- if you want to add new item to list then

  ```
  // add item
  for (i=0;i<MAX;i++) // find first deleted item
   if (data[i].deleted)
    {
    data[i].deleted=false; 
    data[i].cnt=0;
    // copy/set your data
    break;
    }
  ```
- and now in the background once in a while (on timer or whatever)
- scann data[] an all undeleted items with cnt == 0 set as deleted (+ free its dynamic memory if it has any)

[Note]

- to avoid multi-thread access problems implement single global lock per data list
- and program it so you cannot scann data while any data[i].cnt is changing
- one bool and one DWORD suffice for this if you do not want to use OS locks

  ```
  // globals
  bool data_cnt_locked=false;
  DWORD data_cnt=0;
  ```
- now any change of data[i].cnt modify like this:

  ```
  // start use of data[i]
  while (data_cnt_locked) Sleep(1);
  data_cnt++;
  data[i].cnt++;
  data_cnt--;
  ```
- and modify delete scan like this

  ```
  while (data_cnt) Sleep(1);
  data_cnt_locked=true;
  Sleep(1);
  if (data_cnt==0) // just to be sure
  for (i=0;i<MAX;i++) // here scan for items to delete ...
   if (!data[i].cnt)
    if (!data[i].deleted)
    {
    data[i].deleted=true; 
    data[i].cnt=0;
    // release your dynamic data ...
    }
  data_cnt_locked=false;
  ```

PS.

- do not forget to play with the sleep times a little to suite your needs
- lock free algorithm sleep times are sometimes dependent on OS task/scheduler
- this is not really an lock free implementation
- because while GC is at work then all is locked
- but if ather than that multi access is not blocking to each other
- so if you do not run GC too often you are fine

Comment: btw after moving to W7 platform for more robust applications I use  locks with access order stack (do not change the access order) so slower unlucky threads will not freeze to death because on W7 many of my old lock free multi-thread programs stops working safely (scheduller behaviour has changed somehow) especially with USB device drivers usage

Comment: doesn't solve the problem of taking a reference before incrementing the counter in a wait-free manner. A big lock is a big problem. Small locks in the data structure won't work correctly (reference before increment).

Comment: Yes of course you can not use reference before cnt update. if you do than it is all broke  ... If you want to use references without any kind of management than you can not solve this by any means !!!

Comment: But the problem is that in non-managed languages you have to do the management yourself, and my question is how to do the management. As I said, using the GC is fine, if you explain how the GC knows that you have a pointer in a register.

Comment: the delete scan (last code block) is the GC !!! and the rest is the management arround. I do not use any kind of build in GC ... only mine own

Comment: several problems, you have no guarantee that the GC will ever run (if at all times there's at least one thread which currently modifies the count), if the GC runs it blocks everyone, thus, it can't claim to be wait-free, not even lock-free. the GC has to literally scan every data item. If it's 32GB of 64 byte structures, that will take some time and while the GC does that nobody can modify anything. Do you have any suggestion on how to prevent the GC from blocking anyone (thus making it wait-free) and preventing the GC from being blocked indefinitely?

Comment: the runtime of the GC isn't a major problem that can be optimized, the other issues are the problem.

Comment: The only thing that is blocked is GC ... and only for the time that ussage flag is updated which occurs durring new/delete/copy instance only not the usage of data !!! so I do not see any blocking issues with that (unles your threads are with nasty data access). in that case you still can segmentate your data to more locks and use each one segment as separate block (with its own GC) ...

Comment: "while (data_cnt_locked) Sleep(1);" was in your multi-threaded version, that's a sleep before data access, isn't it?

Comment: and of course, nothing stops one of your threads to get a pointer to the data, be interrupted, have the GC release it, then your thread resumes increments the counter (after the GC done freeing the memory) and crashing. It doesn't make a difference if your pointer is a struct data *, or and integer into an array, both need to be first loaded into a variable before the right counter can be incremented, and between the two operations the GC isn't prevented from trashing your memory.

Comment: // start use of data[i]
while (data_cnt_locked) Sleep(1);
data_cnt++;
data[i].cnt++;
data_cnt--;
--- that's where you have a sleep inside the algorithm.

Comment: 1.you can use OS locks for the whole thing or use your own lock-mechanizm as i wrote before, that code is what I used before ordered locks to show you how to implement locks to it. 2.access to data[].cnt is not data access it is just set/res flag that item will/is be used by some thread. 3.data_cnt is also just a flag that some thread will be new/del/copy data pointer (changeing data[].cnt change) shortly to prevent GC from runnung. To avoid miss locks you have to set the sleep times according to your OS scheduler as I also wrote before.

Comment: Without more info about your actual implementation of your multi-thread vs multi-data architecture there is all just guess work about what if or could be happening ... which is without direct implementation and debug pointless

Comment: again, if you use any locks, any locks at all in the middle of the algorithm, you lose wait-freedom. I understand your implementation, and while it works, it provides a weaker guarantee, lock-free at best, for it to be wait-free you must remove the lock on data[i].cnt, see, you can't access the data without incrementing data[i].cnt, so your algorithm must WAIT until this can be done, no more wait-freedom. you code will block data access in a read-only thread for as long as it takes to run the GC. That lock must be removed. ..... next comment

Comment: ..... instead of having arbitrarily long pauses (waiting for GC before accessing data) I could easily add a mutex for each pointer, sure the pointers would be twice as large, but I could use a spin-lock, or something similar, and I could release memory immediately while not having to wait for a global GC. But it's still unacceptable, data access have to wait for an unknown amount of time, thus making it merely lock-free, not wait-free. Lock free is much easier, wait-free has strict requirements on run time. Locking to wait for another thread is not allowed, locking to wait for GC more so.

Comment: So, instead of having the lock on GC, struct ptr { data * ptr; mutext_t mutex; } data * acquire_ref(struct ptr P) { lock_mutex(P.mutex); P.ptr->use_cnt++; unlock_mutex(P.mutex); return P.ptr; } ... this way the contention is on each pointer, an pauses shorter, but there still are pauses of unknown length, theoretically unlimited. A thread acquires mutex, gets interrupted, the no other thread can continue until it gets the CPU back to finish getting the reference. But at least other pointers can be accessed.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if your thread (not GC) has to ever wait on a lock (spinlock, mutex, semaphore) you've lost wait-freedom. So a wait-free gadget must be able to acquire a pointer to data without waiting. And I'm sorry, but your code violates that constraint, hence isn't wait-free. It's probably possible to make the code wait-free, but the current version isn't. Let's see. Let's make the GC always wait for threads (downside, the GC may never run), so, why not have two variables per data, usecnt and timer, every time you use data you increment usecnt (atomic increment, no wait) ....

Comment: ..... the timer is always set to some value, e.g. 8, so before you use data  data[i].usecnt++;data[i].timer=8; ... the GC will do this, if (data[i].usecnt==0) { if (data[i].timer==0) free_data(i); else atomic_dec(data[i].timer); } .... so, the GC will release memory if it wasn't used (pointed to by anyone, data structure or thread) for 8 cycles of GC. But there's a problem, while this works, it has no upper bound on memory usage. It's wait-free. All a thread must do is get a pointer do an atomic increment, and a set, which are all operations which have no overhead over cache bouncing.

Comment: However, there's the problem of the upper bound on memory usage. In practice it might be acceptable, but I'd rather find something better, e.g. hazard pointers or a combination of things. ..... And back to our discussion, is it clear why your algorithm is not wait-free? ....... you would have a wait-point every time you follow a pointer, N for a liked list, and log(N) for a tree. Most of these data structures are riddled with pointers, every time you touch one you have to increment the count, and possibly wait.

Answer (score 0):

I think atomic operations for increment/decrement and compare-and-swap would solve this problem.

Idea:

- All resources have a counter which is modified with atomic operations. The counter is initially zero.
- Before using a resource: "Acquire" it by atomically incrementing its counter. The resource can be used if and only if the incremented value is greater than zero.
- After using a resource: "Release" it by atomically decrementing its counter. The resource should be disposed/freed if and only if the decremented value is equal to zero.
- Before disposing: Atomically compare-and-swap the counter value with the minimum (negative) value. Dispose will not happen if a concurrent thread "Acquired" the resource in between.

You haven't specified a language for your question. Here goes an example in c#:

```cs
class MyResource
{
    // Counter is initially zero. Resource will not be disposed until it has
    // been acquired and released.
    private int _counter;

    public bool Acquire()
    {
        // Atomically increment counter.
        int c = Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);

        // Resource is available if the resulting value is greater than zero.
        return c > 0;
    }

    public bool Release()
    {
        // Atomically decrement counter.
        int c = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter);

        // We should never reach a negative value
        Debug.Assert(c >= 0, "Resource was released without being acquired");

        // Dispose when we reach zero
        if (c == 0)
        {
            // Mark as disposed by setting counter its minimum value.
            // Only do this if the counter remain at zero. Atomic compare-and-swap operation.
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _counter, int.MinValue, c) == c)
            {
                // TODO: Run dispose code (free stuff)
                return true; // tell caller that resource is disposed
            }
        }

        return false; // released but still in use
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// "r" is an instance of MyResource

bool acquired = false;

try
{
    if (acquired = r.Acquire())
    {
        // TODO: Use resource
    }
}
finally
{
    if (acquired)
    {
        if (r.Release())
        {
            // Resource was disposed.
            // TODO: Nullify variable or similar to let GC collect it.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't explain how to prevent memory release if you dereferenced a pointer and updated the counter.

Comment: Doesn't it? I think it does.

Comment: @Martin: If you would acquire a resource and dereference it without releasing it first, then you would break the usage pattern. Is this something that you need to support? I don't see any reason for that. Please explain.

Comment: if you dereference after acquiring, you're right, but you can't call acquire without having a pointer, e.g. in a register. that's a low-level dereference without acquiring, after which you acquire, then do the proper high-level dereference. (assume the language is C/C++)

Comment: @Martin: But you should not have any pointers to the resource unless you have acquired access to it. Otherwise the pointer itself would be the resource, right?

Comment: in unmanaged languages it's a chicken and egg problem. You can't increment a value in an object without having a pointer to the structure. And I need a way to prevent the structure from being freed in that moment between the two actions. (R1=data_offset, atomic_inc mem[R1+counter_offset]).

Comment: @Martin: But why do you keep pointers to a resource that you have not acquired access to? Is there any reason that you cannot design your code so that you don't keep pointers to released resources? I think I'm not fully understanding your situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49642/discussion-between-martin-and-marten-wikstrom)